# Merging text files based on a prefix key

Tags: fastest-code, sorting

Imagine an ordered file set : `file1`, `file2`, ... `fileN`.

Each file is a textual file that is made of lines that have the same format : A concatenation of a fixed-size key (the same among all the file set) and a variable length value.

The merging algorithm is very similar to `UPSERT` :

- To merge 2 files:

  - Iterate on all lines of the first file.

    - If the key of the current line is not in the second file, emit the current line.
    - If the key of the current line is in the second file, emit *only* the line of the second file
  - For each line of the second file that has a key not present in the first file emit the line of the second file.
- If more than 2 files are to be merged, each file is merged to the result of the previous merge. The result of `merge(file1, file2, file3, file4)` is defined as the result of `merge(merge(merge(file1, file2), file3), file4)`.

As an example, we take the length of the key of `4` :

```
$ cat file1
0010THIS_IS_LINE_1_FROM_FILE1
0011THIS_IS_LINE_2_FROM_FILE1
00A0THIS_IS_LINE_3_FROM_FILE1
$ cat file2
0010THIS_IS_LINE_1_FROM_FILE2
0100THIS_IS_LINE_2_FROM_FILE2
$ cat file3
0100EMPTY_LINE
0011EMPTY_LINE
```

Will result in :

```
$ merge --key-size=4 file1 file2 file3
0010THIS_IS_LINE_1_FROM_FILE2
0011EMPTY_LINE
00A0THIS_IS_LINE_3_FROM_FILE1
0100EMPTY_LINE
```

Several precisions :

- Textual data is made of printable `ASCII7` chars plus tabs and spaces.
- Preserving order is nice, but not required
- Uniqueness of key is obviously required
- Multicore-aware algorithms are allowed.
- The first file is usually bigger than the others.

Comment: How are you going to check which code is the fastest?

Comment: How should my program know how long the key is?

Comment: @PeterTaylor using `ENV` var or cli arguments are perfectly valid solutions. Edited the example to reflect that.

Comment: @ProgramFOX i'll be using `time` on a 15GiB + 4x10MiB dataset on a 4-way i5. I'm adding the fact that the 1rst file is _usually_ bigger than the others.

Comment: @SteveSchnepp: And how will you handle different languages?

Comment: @ProgramFOX I was thinking about having a winner per language. But we could also make them compete alltogether and start holy wars :)

Comment: @ProgramFOX the main purpose of that question is to have fun crafting a solution. As I already did it internally, it isn't as easy as it looks :)

Comment: Winner per language is a good idea, except that this site only allows one winner.

Comment: Interesting fact is that we only have Perl solutions :) I'll be posting my own solution later, as I didn't want to hamper creativity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## perl, memory-constrained:

Since rubik mentioned it, here's code for when you haven't the memory to keep all of your keys in memory. Basically we just use the filesystem as a dumb key/value store (you could easily use eg DBM or what have you instead).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec ();
use File::Path qw(make_path remove_tree);
use File::Glob ':globally';
use Path::Iterator::Rule;

my $key_size = $ARGV[0] =~ /--key-size=(\d+)/ ?
               (shift @ARGV, $1) : 4;

my $BASE = File::Spec->catfile( File::Spec->tmpdir(), "merger" );

sub pathify {
  my ($key, $mkdirs) = @_;
  my @path = ($BASE, split //, $key);
  my $dirpart = File::Spec->catdir( @path );
  make_path( $dirpart )  if  $mkdirs;
  return File::Spec->catfile( $dirpart, $key );
}

sub set {
  my ($key, $value) = @_;
  open my $fh, '>', pathify($key, 1) || die "open(w) $key failed: $!";
  print { $fh } $value;
  close $fh;
}

sub get {
  my ($key) = @_;
  open my $fh, '<', pathify($key) || die "open(r) $key failed: $!";
  chomp(my $x = <$fh>);
  close $fh;
  return $x;
}

remove_tree( $BASE );

my %keys;
while(@ARGV) {
  my $fn = shift;
  open my $fh, "<", $fn || die "can't open $fn for reading: $!";
  while(<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    set( substr($_, 0, $key_size), substr($_, $key_size) );
  }
  close $fh || die "can't close $fn: $!";
}

my $next = Path::Iterator::Rule->new->file->iter( $BASE );
while( defined( $_ = $next->() ) ) {
  (undef,undef,$_) = File::Spec->splitpath( $_ );
  print $_.get($_)."\n";
}

remove_tree( $BASE );
```

I felt bad about using a non-core module, Path::Iterator::Rule, but it wasn't worth reinventing the wheel just to avoid the dependency - it's a great module.

You could adapt this to preserve order by changing what is stored in the file from just the $value to include the $order and $value as well. This is trivial because we only ever add keys to the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

## perl

I'm sure this can be done a few percent faster in some other language, but perl makes this super quick to implement at the optimal big-O level, and likely performs well enough. This code preserves order.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $key_size = $ARGV[0] =~ /--key-size=(\d+)/ ?
               (shift @ARGV, $1) : 4;

sub slurp {
  my $fn = shift;
  open my $fh, "<", $fn || die "can't open $fn for reading: $!";
  my (%keys, @order);
  while(<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my $key = substr $_, 0, $key_size;
    push @order, $key;
    $keys{$key} = substr $_, $key_size;
  }
  close $fh || die "can't close $fn: $!";
  return [ \@order, \%keys ];
}

$_ = slurp shift @ARGV;
my @order = @{ $_->[0] };
my %keys  = %{ $_->[1] };
while(@ARGV) {
  my ($order2, $keys2) = @{slurp shift @ARGV};
  $keys{$_} = delete $keys2->{$_}  for (grep { exists $keys2->{$_} } @order);
  for (grep { exists $keys2->{$_} } @{$order2}) {
    $keys{$_} = $keys2->{$_};
    push @order, $_;
  }
}

print "$_$keys{$_}\n"  for  @order;
```

Test output:

```
ski@anito$ perl merger.pl --key-size=4 file1 file2  file3
0010THIS_IS_LINE_1_FROM_FILE2
0011EMPTY_LINE
00A0THIS_IS_LINE_3_FROM_FILE1
0100EMPTY_LINE
```

And here's a slightly faster version that doesn't preserve order:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $key_size = $ARGV[0] =~ /--key-size=(\d+)/ ?
               (shift @ARGV, $1) : 4;

my %keys;
while(@ARGV) {
  my $fn = shift;
  open my $fh, "<", $fn || die "can't open $fn for reading: $!";
  while(<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    $keys{substr $_, 0, $key_size} = substr $_, $key_size;
  }
  close $fh || die "can't close $fn: $!";
}

print "$_$keys{$_}\n"  for  keys %keys;
```

Comment: Can this program process a 15Gib dataset + 4 * 10Mib like specified by the OP on a machine with less RAM?

Comment: Hmm, I missed that bit. It probably wouldn't work as written above if you have less than ~15GiB ram. The easiest fix would probably be to tie() the hash to a DBM file.

Comment: @rubik thx, I didn't say that the machine had less RAM, but I used a 15GiB file to make it obvious :)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see the 15GiB bit at first. Who has time to read comments? ;-) BTW, I have 16GiB of memory on my server downstairs, so it's not entirely a given that the data set can't fit in memory. My other entry keeps the data on disk instead of in memory.